# SQL query to derive the the timeclock data from the measures table

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, big thank you for looking into this.

We have a table called measures which records that staff activity in the lab as shown below:

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║ staf_id ║     start_time      ║      stop_time      ║ task_id ║ fruit_tested ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║     123 ║ 2016-06-01 10:00:00 ║ 2016-06-01 13:15:00 ║       1 ║           90 ║
║  2 ║     123 ║ 2016-06-01 15:20:00 ║ 2016-06-01 18:30:00 ║       2 ║           60 ║
║  3 ║     333 ║ 2016-06-02 10:30:30 ║ 2016-06-02 15:45:00 ║       1 ║           30 ║
║  4 ║     333 ║ 2016-06-03 09:00:00 ║ 2016-06-03 09:45:00 ║       1 ║           60 ║
║  5 ║     555 ║ 2016-06-01 07:00:00 ║ 2016-06-01 11:15:00 ║       1 ║           90 ║
║  6 ║     555 ║ 2016-06-01 11:30:00 ║ 2016-06-01 13:00:00 ║       1 ║           30 ║
║  7 ║     123 ║ 2016-06-02 10:00:00 ║ 2016-06-02 14:00:00 ║       3 ║           30 ║
║  8 ║     333 ║ 2016-06-03 10:20:00 ║ 2016-06-03 13:15:15 ║       1 ║           30 ║
║  9 ║     333 ║ 2016-06-04 07:50:20 ║ 2016-06-04 12:30:50 ║       1 ║           60 ║
║ 10 ║     555 ║ 2016-06-03 05:30:00 ║ 2016-06-03 10:00:00 ║       1 ║           60 ║
║ 11 ║     123 ║ 2016-06-03 06:00:00 ║ 2016-06-03 10:30:30 ║       4 ║           90 ║
║ 12 ║     123 ║ 2016-06-03 12:15:04 ║ 2016-06-03 12:45:50 ║       5 ║           90 ║
║ 13 ║     123 ║ 2016-06-03 17:10:00 ║ 2016-06-03 19:00:00 ║       1 ║           30 ║
║ 14 ║     123 ║ 2016-06-04 12:15:04 ║ 2016-06-04 15:00:00 ║       1 ║           30 ║
║ 15 ║     123 ║ 2016-06-04 15:10:00 ║ 2016-06-04 15:30:00 ║       2 ║           90 ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════╩══════════════╝
```

Currently, we have an issue with our real timeClock table, as an interim solution I would like to retrieve time clock details of each staff for each day from the measures table, where the clock_in will be the first measures.start_time for the day and clock_out will be the the last measures.stop_time for the day of that staff as shown below:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ staff_id ║      clock_in       ║      clock_out      ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║      123 ║ 2016-06-01 10:00:00 ║ 2016-06-01 18:30:00 ║
║      123 ║ 2016-06-02 10:00:00 ║ 2016-06-02 14:00:00 ║
║      123 ║ 2016-06-03 06:00:00 ║ 2016-06-03 19:00:00 ║
║      123 ║ 2016-06-04 12:15:04 ║ 2016-06-04 15:30:00 ║
║      333 ║ 2016-06-02 10:30:30 ║ 2016-06-02 15:45:00 ║
║      333 ║ 2016-06-03 09:00:00 ║ 2016-06-03 13:15:15 ║
║      333 ║ 2016-06-04 07:50:20 ║ 2016-06-04 12:30:50 ║
║      555 ║ 2016-06-01 07:00:00 ║ 2016-06-01 13:00:00 ║
║      555 ║ 2016-06-03 05:30:00 ║ 2016-06-03 10:00:00 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

How do I achieve this result? Any suggestion would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: So you want the min and max time stamps for each user for each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is easy, just an aggregation:

```
select staff_id, min(start_time) as clock_in, max(stop_time) as clock_out
from measures
group by staff_id, date(start_time)
order by staff_id, min(start_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select staff_id,
    min(start_time) clock_in,
    max(stop_time) clock_out
from measures
group by staff_id,cast(start_time as date)
order by 1,2
```

Comment: How is this different from the first answer given?